# Looking to write my own 'Application Whitelisting Tool' Something like Bit9?

Tags: c#, python, process, whitelist

Playing around with project ideas that I might actually use, figured I might try to write my own simple version of Bit9 Parity, in either C# or Python. My question is what is the best way to go about doing this. I've googled .Net functionality for prevent processes from executing, but I havn't really found what I'm looking for. What I'd like to do is monitory the system memory as a whole, and deny any process or application from starting unless specifically identified in a list. ProcessWatcher caught my eye, but is that not for a specific process ID. How do I block ALL other processes from starting? Is this possible in .Net? What about python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`blog post`](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx) ([`Using WMI to monitor process creation, deletion and modification in .NET`](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx)) shows how to do that. With a few changes, you should be able to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I block ALL other processes from starting?

Deep, mysterious OS API magic.  After all, you're interfering with how the OS works.  You must, therefore patch or hook into the OS itself.

> Is this possible in .Net? What about python?

It doesn't involve time-travel, anti-gravity or perpetual motion.  It can be done.

It's a matter of figuring out (1) which OS API calls are required to put your new hook into the OS, and (2) implementing a call from the OS to your code.

1. Is really hard.
2. Is really easy.